# System.IO.Stream disposable with a reader

Tags: c#, .net, file-io, stream

Can't remember where I read it, but I remember a MS guy saying that once you create a reader around a System.IO.Stream, then the stream is not longer responsible for the disposal of the stream.

Is this true? Can someone confirm this? Maybe provide a reference.

This means the outer using in this code is redundant

```
using (var s = new FileStream(@"c:\file.txt",FileMode.Open)) {
    using (var reader = new StreamReader(s)) {
         reader.ReadToEnd();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both `FileStream` and `StreamReader` implement `IDisposable`, so I would use both `using`'s regardless, that way if the underlying implementation were to change, however unlikely, your code would still be good.

Comment: StreamReader.ReadToEnd is fine - it's inherited from TextReader.

Comment: +1. This will result in Stream.Dispose being called twice, but IDisposable.Disposable implementations should ignore all calls after the first.  Thus you can and generally should always call Dispose on a disposable class.

Answer (score 2):

read the approved answer to this question:

[Who Disposes of an IDisposable public property?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/674879/who-disposes-of-an-idisposable-public-property/675001#675001)

It says that StreamReader always disposes the underlying stream.

Comment: This will allow concise constructs like    using (var reader = new StreamReader(new FileStream(@"c:\file.txt",FileMode.Open))) { reader.ReadToEnd(); }

Answer (score 2):

If isn't redundant, for the reason that the "`new StreamReader(s)`" line could fail (throw an exception). That would mean that *no* `using` block is going to `Dispose()` the stream. In reality, this is unlikely... but it could! For example, the stream might be non-readable (or whatever).

Thus, it is always best to guard such initialization; far better to be disposed twice than not at all. Plus it makes it obvious to the reader (and any code analysis tools) that you have **definitely** cleaned up after yourself.

Comment: If the construction of the StreamReader throws, the using of the Reader isn't entered yet, so it won't Dispose and it doesn't have to.
The outer using is active but it will check s != null and not Dispose either. And that is correct too.

Comment: No - you're missing the point; the OP asks "is the outer using redundant" - no: it isn't. If you take it away, then if the StreamReader throws during creation then the FileStream will *not* be disposed. Only finalized, eventually.

Answer (score 1):

For a reference you'll have to look at the [MSDN page for the protected Dispose(bool)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh40558e.aspx) that indeed states that a TextReader will close the underlying stream.

But I agree with Mitch Wheat that it is still a good idea to use a nested `using{}`, this [MSDN example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yhfzs7at.aspx) also does that.