# Edit text file after creation

Tags: c#

I am creating a text file if it doesn't exist and then immediately after I am adding text to that file.  However, my compiler says it's being used by another process, which I assume is because it was just created.  How can I fix this?

Code excerpt-

```
//If the text document doesn't exist, create it
if (!File.Exists(set.cuLocation))
{
    File.CreateText(set.cuLocation);
}

//If the text file after being moved is empty, edit it to say the previous folder's name
System.IO.StreamReader objReader = new System.IO.StreamReader(set.cuLocation);
set.currentUser = objReader.ReadLine();
objReader.Close();
if (set.currentUser == null)
{
    File.WriteAllText(set.cuLocation, set.each2);
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`CreateText` method actually creates (and returns) a `StreamWriter` object. You're never closing that stream.
What is it that you're trying to accomplish? Why do you attempt to read from an empty file?
Just keep a reference to that `StreamWriter` you're creating and use it for writing.

```
StreamWriter sw = File.CreateText(set.cuLocation);
```

and then call `sw.Write` etc.

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamwriter.write.aspx for reference.

When you're done, call `sw.Close`.

Note that it could happen that an exception is thrown while you're writing. This could prevent the stream from being closed.

A good pattern that addresses this issue is to wrap the `StreamWriter` in a `using` block. See this question for more details: [Is it necessary to wrap StreamWriter in a using block?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1018963/is-it-necessary-to-wrap-streamwriter-in-a-using-block)

Comment: How do I close that stream?

Comment: @TheUnrealMegashark I do suggest that you simply read the documentation. The example there shows you how to do it.

Comment: @TheUnrealMegashark, just add `.Close()` at the end.

Comment: Always better to use 'using' while using StreamReader/Writer.

Answer (score 1):

Don't forget call Close method:

```
if (!File.Exists(set.cuLocation))
{
    File.Create(set.cuLocation)
        .Close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can enclose it in a `using` block which will automatically close the stream for you:

```
if (!File.Exists(set.cuLocation))
{
    File.CreateText(set.cuLocation);
}

using(System.IO.StreamReader objReader = new System.IO.StreamReader(set.cuLocation))
{
   set.currentUser = objReader.ReadLine();
}

if (set.currentUser == null)
{
    File.WriteAllText(set.cuLocation, set.each2);
}
```