# Should we implement IDisposable if one member is IDisposable?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, idisposable

I think so. But take a look at a built-in class in ASP.NET:

```
public sealed class HttpPostedFile
{
    public Stream InputStream { get; }   // Stream implements IDisposable
    // other properties and methods
}
```

Suppose I have an instance of `HttpPostedFile` called `file`. Since there is no `Dispose` method to explicitly invoke, `file.InputStream.Dispose()` won't be invoked until it's destructed, which I think goes against the original intention of `IDisposable`. I think the correct implementation should contain a standard `IDisposable` implementation. So, if one of the members implements `IDisposable`, the class needs to implement it too.

What are your opinions? It seems to be a bit complicated.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In general, you should implement `IDisposable` if you **own** the resource represented by the property - see [this question for a discussion on this subject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/674879/who-disposes-of-an-idisposable-public-property).

I'd say that because HttpPostedFile is instantiated during processing of an HTTP request, it doesn't own the stream, and hence doesn't dispose it.  The stream will be disposed when the HTTP request processing finishes.

Comment: Oh it seems that my question is a duplicated one. Thanks for the link. I'll accept this answer in 1 min.

Comment: +1, generally it's only your responsibility to dispose of an object if you are the one that constructed it..

Answer (score 2):

If your class creates one or more `IDisposable` objects and holds the only references to them, then your class should almost certainly implement `IDisposable` and dispose the `IDisposable` objects it created.  If one or more `IDisposable` objects will be passed into the constructor of your class, then you need to consider a few scenarios:

1. Your creator may want to keep using the `IDisposable` after you're done with it, and will certainly know when it's no longer needed (the semantics of your class would let him know you're done with it).
2. Your creator won't want to use the `IDisposable` after you're done with it, and may not know when you're going to be done with it.
3. Your class may be used in some circumstances corresponding to (1) above, and in some circumstances (2), but your creator will know in advance which circumstance applies.
4. Your creator can't predict whether he's going to want to keep using the object after you're done with it.

For scenario #1, there's no need for you to implement `IDisposable`, though it might not be a bad idea to implement a do-nothing `IDisposable` handler and have your consumers use it, in case another scenario applies in future.

For scenario #2, your object should take ownership of the `IDisposable`, and should `Dispose` it when done.  I don't really like having objects take unconditional ownership of `IDisposable`s; I prefer to implement things as in #3.

There are two ways of handling #3.  The one I prefer is for your object to take a parameter (either a `Boolean` or an `enum`) along with the `IDisposable`, indicating whether it is supposed to take ownership of the `IDisposable`.  Your class unconditionally implements `IDisposable`; the implementation disposes of any objects it has taken ownership of, but not those it hasn't.  An alternative is to have two subclasses with a common base class - one subclass implements `IDisposable` and the other does not.  I prefer the former pattern, because it allows for the addition of a method to replace an `IDisposable` with a new one (of which it may or may not take ownership).  For example, if I were implementing a control with an `Image` property, I would have a `SetImage` method which with a parameter to specify whether the control should own the passed-in image; that method would `Dispose` the old image if it owned it, and could then either take ownership of the new image or not.

```
bool OwnMyImage;
Image MyImage;
void SetImage(Image NewImage, bool TakeOwnership)
{
    IDisposable oldDisposable; // Could reuse one variable for multiple IDisposables
    if (OwnMyImage)
    {
        oldDisposable = Threading.Interlocked.Exchange(MyImage, null);
        if (oldDisposable != null)
        {
            oldDisposable.Dispose();
        }
    }
    OwmMyImage = TakeOwnership;
    MyImage = NewImage;
}
```

Scenario #4 is complicated; the best way to handle it is probably for your object to implement `IDisposable` by raising a `Disposed` event.  Your creator can use that event to do either `Dispose` the object if you were the last one using it, or adjust a flag or counter so that other code will know the object shouldn't be left undisposed on your behalf.

Answer (score 0):

It depends.

`Stream` is also implemented by `TextStream` (possibly on top of `StringBuilder`), so no unmanaged resources are required.

`HttpPostedFile` may not use any unmanaged resources at all, so it's safe to postpone deconstruction until the garbage collector sees fit.