# ORA-4030 Oracle : How to resolve

Tags: sql, oracle, memory

In our oracle server(10 g), we are getting ORA-4030  error  on sometimes.

> ORA-04030: out of process memory when trying to allocate nn bytes

We understood it is related with memory size adjustment. We are trying some memory settings.

Other than this, wanted to know,

(1) Any specific SQL query usages will be cause this kind of error

(2) any Oracle SQL query tuning can be applied to avoid this

Your replies will help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

1) The sorts,distinct, group and join hashes are the most probably to give you this error!
2) What OS do you use? In linux you can see what resources do you for your users with ulimit -a.

You should increase the memory per process for PGA.

Regards

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am using in Window 2003 server

Answer (score 1):

One thing which could be contributing to the error, is not freeing cursors. In .net a SQLStatement = a db cursor. Make sure that the applications are closing (and disposing) the SQL statements it is using.

Comment: Thanks for reply.  This would be helpful. We will check for any such cases.  If you have any more Links about this, please share. Thanks

Comment: This code pattern will cleanup on statements (close dispose) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60919/is-sqlcommand-dispose-enough