# C# application stops

Tags: c#, sql

I have the following code:

```
OpeningForm of = new OpeningForm();
of.ShowDialog();

SqlConnection SqlBaglanti = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=MolaTakip; integrated security=true");
SqlBaglanti.Open();

SqlCommand komut = new SqlCommand("AgentBilgisiDondur')", SqlBaglanti);
komut.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
komut.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LoginName", ThisAgent.LoginName);

SqlDataReader dr = komut.ExecuteReader();

while (dr.Read())
{
    ThisAgent.AgentID = int.Parse(dr["UserID"].ToString());
    ThisAgent.AgentAdi = dr["UserName"].ToString();
}
SqlBaglanti.Close();

FileStream fs = new FileStream(@"C:\agent.bin", FileMode.OpenOrCreate);

BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();

bf.Serialize(fs, ThisAgent);
```

All of this codes written in the `Form_Load` event. But form loads at

```
SqlDataReader dr = komut.ExecuteReader();
```

line, further commands are not running.

Comment: Are you getting an exception? Also your code is badly leaking handles. You are not disposing any of the IDisposable resources you are dealing with.

Comment: Run your program in the debugger, and see if an exception pops up?

Comment: No exceptions, i also followed my code with break points. I'm %100 sure about it's not going further from that line.

Comment: Add a try...catch around all code and get the exception(s). If there are no exceptions, the resultset might be empty.

Comment: You should post your sql and exception you got

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure about the syntax?

```
SqlCommand komut = new SqlCommand("AgentBilgisiDondur')", SqlBaglanti);
```

I think you have a stored procedure which is called AgentBilgisiDondur not AgentBilgisiDondur')

```
SqlCommand komut = new SqlCommand("AgentBilgisiDondur", SqlBaglanti);
```

An advice: Also try to use English because your columns are in English such as `UserName`. So you can try `ReturnAgentInformation` ;)

Answer (score 0):

You must open the database connection using the sql command and not the sqlconnection itself.
You rightly passed t to the command. Now the command must open it.

Remove `SqlBaglanti.Open();` before you call the `ExecuteReader()` add this line:

> `SqlCommand.Connection.Open();`

Comment: it is wrong see http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/9kcbe65k(v=vs.80).aspx you can open connection

Comment: It is not wrong. Please see related post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60919/is-sqlcommand-dispose-enough

Comment: -1, consider this answer is not correct, both connections are the same reference

Answer (score 0):

the mistake is that you have not correct parameters (are you missed some parameters like passowrd agent for your stored procedure or the name of stored procedure is wrong) check please