# how to create a link in gridview in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, linkbutton

I am trying to create a webpage that has a gridview. this gridview is supposed to have a link like below

```
http://localhost/Test.aspx?code=123
```

when the user clicks one of the rows' link in gridview, it will open a blank page and display some result.

here is how I bind data to the gridview but I dont know how to set the link

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string firma_no = logoFrmNr.ToString().PadLeft(3, '0');
    string active_period = logoFrmPeriod.PadLeft(2, '0');

    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(conStr);
    string selectSql = @"SELECT 
                                LOGICALREF,
                                CODE , 
                                DEFINITION_ ,
                                FROM 
                                LG_CLFLINE";

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(selectSql, conn);
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    da.Fill(dt);
    GridView1.DataSource = dt;
    GridView1.DataBind();

    conn.Close();
}
```

here is the markup

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" EnableModelValidation="True">
</asp:GridView>
```

How can I make a link out of CODE column?

Comment: Pls show us your markup code!

Comment: Please see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60919/is-sqlcommand-dispose-enough  SqlConnection and SqlCommand are unmanaged classes.  Your code will likely result in hard to identify issues.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

to me it would be something like

```
<asp:DataGrid id="MyDataGrid" 
           GridLines="Both"
           AutoGenerateColumns="false"
           runat="server">

         <HeaderStyle BackColor="#aaaadd"/>

         <Columns>

            <asp:HyperLinkColumn
                 HeaderText="Select an Item"
                 DataNavigateUrlField="code"
                 DataNavigateUrlFormatString="http://localhost/Test.aspx?code={0}"
                 Target="_blank"/>

         </Columns>

      </asp:DataGrid>
```

Comment: Surprisingly, the `DataNavigateUrlFormatString` doesn't work like that.  I wish it did, but it's used to format numerical values. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.hyperlinkfield.datanavigateurlformatstring(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: My mistake.  I was thinking of something else.

Answer (score 12):

There's a trick to this.  The Hyperlinkcolumn won't work, because you can't format the link.  You want to use a boundfield and format the text.  Like so

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" EnableModelValidation="True">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Code" HtmlEncode="False" DataFormatString="<a target='_blank' href='Test.aspx?code={0}'>Link Text Goes here</a>" />
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Alternately, you can use a templatefield if you need to designate edit and insert templates.

Comment: where should I add this code? please tell me where I should put this code?

Comment: @Smeegs - you can use a `HyperLink` control inside of a `TemplateField` and format the URL for navigation, see my answer.

Comment: I know, I mention that in my answer. But, unless you're handling an edit and an insert template.  That's overkill to get the same result.

Comment: @Smeegs - completely disagree that a `TemplateField` is overkill unless you are doing an edit or an insert template, it is extremely useful for handling the data binding event (`OnRowBound`) so that you can find the control by ID instead of relying on cell index, because `BoundField`s do not have an `ID` attribute.

Comment: @KarlAnderson It really depends on how you want to use the column.  I completely agree with your example.  In that scenario `TemplateField` is not overkill, it's completely necessary. But, in this scenario, the poster just wants to render a hyperlink.  For the requested functionality creating an entire template compared to formatting a string is overkill.

Comment: @Smeegs - +1 agreed, as long as the OP got the answer they wanted, that is what matters. :-)

Comment: I am confused about the link. I have the same issue and I do not know what link should I place. Please help me

Comment: Here is how I got just the link text only in gridview, which has dynamic text that can't be hard coded as the example above shows `<asp:BoundField DataField="link" HeaderText="link" ReadOnly="True" htmlencode="false" DataFormatString="<a target='{0}' href='{0}'>{0}</a>" />`

Answer (score 11):

Add this to your `Columns` definition in the markup for your grid view:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Hyperlink">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" runat="server" 
            NavigateUrl='<%# Eval("CODE", @"http://localhost/Test.aspx?code={0}") %>' 
            Text='link to code'>
        </asp:HyperLink>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to use a HyperLinkColumn in your markup.

[HyperlinkColumn Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.hyperlinkcolumn%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: Please provide a working example (eg: including code) - link only answers are not allowed as of FAQ.

Answer (score 0):

**HyperLinkField** can be used

```
    <asp:GridView ID="MyGrid" runat="server">  
    <Columns>
    <asp:HyperLinkField DataNavigateUrlFields="Link" DataNavigateUrlFormatString="/{0}" DataTextField="Location" HeaderText="Location" SortExpression="Link" />
    </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
```