# Does creating a new SqlConnection in the constructor close it?

Tags: c#, ado.net, sqlclient

Does instantiating a new SqlConnection in the SqlCommand's constructor close it?

For example:

```
using (SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand(query, new SqlConnection(connString))
{
    // do some stuff
}
```

Will that call .Close() on the connection?

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't aware this was a duplicate. I searched google and couldn't find a concrete answer.

Answer (score 1):

No, it won't. `SqlCommand` doesn't own the connection, so it's not going to `Close` or `Dispose` of its own accord.

You'll need to either call `Close` yourself or, probably better, wrap it in a using statement so that `Dispose` is called when you're finished with it:

```
using (var connection = new SqlConnection(connString))
using (var command = new SqlCommand(query, connection))
{
    // do some stuff
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> No, Disposing of the Command will not close the Connection. A better
>   approach would be to also wrap the SqlCommand in a using block as well
>
> ```
> using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connstring))
> {
>     conn.Open();
>     using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(cmdstring, conn))
>     {
>         cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
>     }
> }
> ```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/60934/64976