# Defensive opening of a database connection with option to retry

Tags: c#, sql-server

Occasionally I am getting a `SqlException` exception on the line marked below.
It occurs when we have network problems and the server cannot be found.

```
public void markComplete(int aTKey)
{
  SqlCommand mySqlCommand = null;
  SqlConnection myConnect = null;
  mySqlCommand = new SqlCommand();
  try
  {
    myConnect = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["foo"].ConnectionString);
    mySqlCommand.Connection = myConnect;
    mySqlCommand.Connection.Open();        //<<<<<<<< EXCEPTION HERE <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
    mySqlCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    mySqlCommand.CommandText =
       " UPDATE dbo.tb_bar " +
       " SET    LastUpdateTime    = CONVERT(Time,GETDATE()) " +
       " WHERE  AKey = " + aTKey;
    mySqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
    mySqlCommand.Connection.Close();
  }
  finally
  {
    if(mySqlCommand != null)
    {
      mySqlCommand.Dispose();
    }
  }
}
```

I have two questions so maybe should split into 2 SO questions:

1. Is my `finally` statement sufficiently defensive ?
2. Rather than just failing how involved would it be to amend the method so instead of crashing it waits for say 10 minutes and then tries again to open the connection - tries a maximum of 3 times and if still no valid connection it moves on?

Comment: If you use `using` for your connection, that `try`-`finally` wouldn't even be necessary. Also note this does not actually catch or process the error.

Comment: By the way, there is no use in first assigning `null` to `mySqlCommand` and then filling it with a new object. That's just code pollution. Fill it with the new object right away.

Comment: In addition to @Nyerguds comment, you can set the connection timeout in the connection string

Comment: I just noticed, the connection itself is never even disposed in this code. Only the command. That's a major flaw. Which, as I said, can be fixed with `using`.

Comment: I would note that your `finally` block is disposing the `SqlCommand`, but not actually closing the `SqlConnection`.  https://stackoverflow.com/q/60919/8915494

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are the uses of "using" in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75401/what-are-the-uses-of-using-in-c-sharp)

Comment: @MiguelA.Arilla All the connection timeout will do is force this code to wait longer before it fails - if the network connection to the DB is dead, then increasing the timeout won't really help.

Comment: @mjwills I think we need to bring in the use of a Catch - whereas `using` is try/finally so I disagree that this is a duplicate of the question you cited

Comment: @Nyerguds - if I need to use a catch clause then is `using` still a good option? I thought it was syntactic sugar for try/finally ?

Comment: @Nyerguds do you have time to post an answer - I think your suggestion concerning disposing of the connection is very valid

Comment: @whytheq `using` automates cleanup, so it is always advised over manually disposing for locally-used disposables. And, if you knew you'd need `catch`, why didn't you add it from the start? An app that doesn't handle its errors _at all_ is _never_ 'defensive'.

Comment: @Nyerguds I agree - if I knew how to defend correctly, which I obviously don't, then I wouldn't have asked the question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. [Use parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8263371/how-can-prepared-statements-protect-from-sql-injection-attacks?rq=1). Do not concatenate strings to create SQL statements. Read about [SQL Injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).
2. Instead of using `try...finally` you can simplify your code with the [`using`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-statement) statement.  You need to dispose all the instances that implements the `IDisposable` interface, so you also need to use the `using` statement with the `SqlConnection`. In fact, it's even more important then disposing the `SqlCommand`, since it allows ADO.Net to use [connection pooling.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql-server-connection-pooling)
3. You don't need to do the entire procedure again and again, just the connection.Open and the ExecuteNonQuery.
4. Using the constructor that accepts a string an SqlConnection saves you the need to set them via properties.
5. You don't need to specify `CommandType.Text` - it's the default value.

Here is a basic implementation of retry logic with some improvements to your code:

```
public void markComplete(int aTKey)
{
    var sql = " UPDATE dbo.tb_bar " +
               " SET    LastUpdateTime    = CONVERT(Time,GETDATE()) " +
               " WHERE  AKey = @aTKey";

    using(var myConnect = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["foo"].ConnectionString))
    {
        using(var mySqlCommand = new SqlCommand(sql, myConnect))
        {
            mySqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@aTKey", SqlDbType.Int).Value = aTKey;

            var success = false;
            var attempts = 0;
            do
            {
                attempts++;
                try
                {
                    mySqlCommand.Connection.Open();  
                    mySqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    success = true;
                }
                catch(Exception ex)
                {
                    // Log exception here
                    Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
                }
            }while(attempts < 3 || !success);
        }   
    }   
}
```

**Update:**

Well, I've had some free time and I remember writing a general retry method a few years back. Couldn't find it but here is the general idea:

```
static void RetryOnException(Action action, int numberOfRetries, int timeoutBetweenRetries)
{
    var success = false;
    var exceptions = new List<Exception>();
    var currentAttempt = 0;
    do
    {
        currentAttempt++;

        try
        {
            action();
            success = true;
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            exceptions.Add(ex);
            Threading.Thread.Sleep(timeoutBetweenRetries);
        }
    } while(!success || currentAttempt < numberOfRetries);

    // Note: The Exception will only be thrown in case all retries fails.
    // If the action completes without throwing an exception at any point, all exceptions before will be swallowed by this method. You might want to log them for future analysis.
    if(!success && exceptions.Count > 0)
    {
        throw new AggregateException("Failed all {numberOfRetries} retries.", exceptions);
    }
}
```

Using this method you can retry all sort of things, while keeping your methods simpler and cleaner.
So here is how it should be used:

```
public void markComplete(int aTKey)
{
    var sql = " UPDATE dbo.tb_bar " +
               " SET    LastUpdateTime    = CONVERT(Time,GETDATE()) " +
               " WHERE  AKey = @aTKey";

    using(var myConnect = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["foo"].ConnectionString))
    {
        using(var mySqlCommand = new SqlCommand(sql, myConnect))
        {
            mySqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@aTKey", SqlDbType.Int).Value = aTKey;
            // You can do this inside a `try...catch` block or let the AggregateException propagate to the calling method
            RetryOnException(
                () => {
                    mySqlCommand.Connection.Open();  
                    mySqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }, 3, 1000);
        }   
    }   
}
```

Comment: @Nyerguds The OP stated they wanted to wait before retrying

Comment: @Nyerguds the OP wanted to wait 10 minutes between retries. I think 1 second is more realistic.

Comment: yes 1000 is fine - I might need to make the time different but I definitely want it to wait

Comment: Ah yes. Fair enough.

Comment: @ZoharPeled (upped) thanks for taking the time to write this method for me - I always mark an answer as correct

Comment: @whytheq I've updated my answer, you should check it out.

Comment: @ZoharPeled - I just hit the big green tick - really appreciate the time you have spent on this

Comment: @ZoharPeled this looks more like functional programming - I never saw this Action object before? but it is like you pass in the method?

Comment: @whytheq Yes, that's a delegate. more information on [`action`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.action(v=vs.110).aspx)